# Add comma to output

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have created a calculator that shows the output of savings with a specific calculation. I just need the result to be formatted with commas and to be currency so it does not show every number after the decimal. For example if the outcome was:

$2500.566695969
I would only want it to show:
$2,500.56

I hope that makes sense, I tried a couple of things to get the comma in the right place but nothing worked. I am a bit newer to jQuery and this is my first attempt at a calculator like this. Any help is really appreciated. Below is my code.

```
function calculate() {
    var savingsVal = (jQuery('#savingsVal').val());
    var totalSavings = 0;
    var regType = (jQuery('#reg-type').val());

    if (filterValues(savingsVal)) {
        totalSavings = savingsVal * 0.15 * 3 - regType * 3;
    }

    jQuery('#totalSavings').val('$' + totalSavings);
}


function filterValues(eVal) {
    return true;
}

jQuery('.results-area').hide();

jQuery('#calculator').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    calculate();
    jQuery('.results-area').show("slow");
    jQuery(this).text( jQuery(this).submit().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") );
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Currency Format Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807155/jquery-currency-format-number)

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm that will format money? Or would you be satisfied using a library that already does this? I would recommend the latter.

Comment: I'd highly recommend you to use a good library like accounting.js. http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/ . It has a method called `formatMoney` that will do everything you want to.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148034/regex-for-number-with-decimals-and-thousand-separator

Comment: I just want it to output in a currency format. Whatever works easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a little obnoxious but below is a working function.

It accepts a string containing a number. It doesn't matter if the string contains a `'$'` or not.

It returns a string formatted with commas without the preceding `'$'`, but this is easily added of course.

```js
function toCurrency(str) {
    let ret = parseFloat(str[0] === '$' ? str.substr(1) : str).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    if (!isNaN(ret))
 return str;
    return ret;
}

let elem = document.getElementById('money');
elem.innerHTML = '$' + toCurrency(elem.innerHTML);
```

```html
<p id="money">$2500.566695969</p>
```

Comment: It doesn't output with a comma though? am I missing something?

Comment: There is a comma? I receive `$2,500.57` as the output.

Comment: Oh I see it, let me give this a try. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Can you tell me the exact value of the `str` argument you used. And what is not working, are there errors?...

Comment: Here is my codepen, I did not see any errors: https://codepen.io/ascarb1/pen/rYXLyg

Comment: You did not even use my function in your code, maybe that's why it's not working?

Comment: I am sorry. I did do it, then deleted it because it did not work. Also I had it in the wrong place. This works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"` instead of your current Regex in the replace function.

Comment: That did not work :/. Do I have it out of place? Or my code incorrect?